# Is an electric lamp a transducer?

Tags: soft-question, electricity, energy-conservation, visible-light, terminology

Silly thought.

A transducer, by definition, is a device that converts variations in one form of energy to another. An electric lamp converts electricity into visible light - the brightness may vary depending upon the electric potential applied.

Is it correct to state an Electric Lamp is a transducer?

Comment: Hello Everyone, Doesn't Wikipedia & Google satisfy you..?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: My apologies to all. When the thought occurred, I just went ahead & posted the query on here without further ado

Comment: Hello there Everyone... There's no necessary for *apologies*. But, Please be careful while posting good questions *next time*..! :)

Comment: @Everyone: like Crazy Buddy said (or implied), it's not really a good idea to just post a question here as soon as it occurs to you. Take a bit of time to check standard references (Wikipedia, Google, etc.) first, and think about how you would try to answer the question yourself. That being said, I don't know that this is really a bad question... it might be off topic, but I'm not going to close it as such unless other people also think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly yes, a transducer converts one form of energy to another. It's more commonly used when you are converting some physical effect into electrical energy as in a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say **YES**. Please keep an eye on our best *reference* - Wikipedia for a list of commonly used [Apps of Transducers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transducer)